# Compare two columns from multiple sheets ans extract values

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

It may be a repeated question, but I couldn't find an effective solution anywhere.

One of my clients needs a weekly update on projects. They download an excel from their ERP consisting of multiple columns and I have to comment status on the last column. 
Every week I will get a fresh copy and all my previous entries will be cleared, then its a repeated job for me. I just want to see what I commented last week and copy paste the same in the new sheet.

Problems:

- The new sheet will be in a mixed order.
- Some new rows will be there and some rows disappear.

**Sheet 1**

[image]

**Sheet 2**

[image: Sheet 2]

For the new rows in Sheet 2, I will update the comments manually. 
But please help me on copying the repeated rows, which I entered on sheet1

Looking for some expert solutions

Thanks

Comment: You couldn't find an 'effective solution' using vlookup?

Comment: But how we add multiple criteria in Vlookup? The actual data is too complicated and have more than 15 columns and 3000 rows

Comment: My bad, after a long time using stack overflow and excel

Comment: Have you tried VBA code?

Comment: Can you share the VBA code

Comment: You can use something like this: https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code. It worked for me.

Input sheet (Sheet1):

[image]

Below is the code:

```
Sub Comapre()

Dim TotalNames As Integer

Dim NameInSheet2 As String, PO As String

TotalNames = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 2 To TotalNames

NameInSheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Value

PO = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

'Finds the cell value in Sheet1

Set cell = Cells.Find(What:=NameInSheet2, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)


    If cell Is Nothing Then

        Else

            'If it found the name then it will compare the PO value

            If cell.Offset(, 1).Value = PO Then

                'If Name and Po value matched then comment will be copied to sheet2.

                Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & i) = cell.Offset(, 2).Value

            End If

        End If

    Next


End Sub
```

Output Sheet(Sheet2):

[image]

Please let me know if my answer fits your question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right a simple [VLOOKUP()](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) should do the job.

I am assuming the PO numbers in a table are unique.

You take new sheet and look for the last comment you had for this PO.

in the Sheet2 eg in cell `C2` you would type like:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!B:C,2,FALSE)
```

This will look up your PO nr 4500253 in the Sheet1 Column B (with an exact match) and return the matched row value from Column C. An error is returned if no match is found.

Comment: If values in columns A and  B matches in both sheets, extract value from column C and insert it in Sheet 2. In short , this is what I am looking for ...

Comment: if your the A-B combination is unique, you can compose an extra column in the sheets combining the A-B values and resulting in a column having unique identifiable values. Then use the unique value for lookup.

Answer (score 0):

using `Dictionary` object

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim cell As Range

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each cell In .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            dict.Item(cell.Value2 & "|" & cell.Offset(, 1).Value2) = cell.Offset(, 2).Value2
        Next
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For Each cell In .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            If dict.exists(cell.Value2 & "|" & cell.Offset(, 1).Value2) Then cell.Offset(, 2).Value = dict.Item(cell.Value2 & "|" & cell.Offset(, 1).Value2)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```